# Android - Sign application using jarsigner

Tags: android, maven, sign

Android uses sign.jar file to sign some of its system applications (Eg: setting). Inorder to gain some extra permissions i need to sign my app using the same signature (platform) as that of setting. I did the signing and it works great.

Is it possible to sign my app using jarsigner instead sign.jar ? My project is using maven so switching from jarsigner to sign.jar for this app alone will break compatibly with other apps.

Answer (score 9):

On Java 1.7 you must user this:

```
jarsigner -sigalg MD5withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore *pathtokey* -storepass *yourpass* -keypass *yourpass* *app.apk* *keyalias*
```

Comment: That's right! Without -siglalg, Java 1.7 would use SHA-256 algo.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this command line

jarsigner -verbose -keystore yourKeyStore.keystore theFile.apk password